# How can i remove Double Quotes from json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string as follows.

```
"{
  "stepno": 1,
  "content": "dddd",
  "icon": "plug icon",
  "header": "Uptime Guarantee",
  "headcolor": "ffffff",
  "tagline": "Check out our plug-in marketplace",
  "taglinecolor": "ffffff",
  "isActive": true
}"
```

I want to remove double quotes from properties like follow.

```
"{
stepno: 1,
content:'', 
icon:'plug icon',  
header:'Uptime Guarantee',
headcolor:'ffffff', 
tagline:'Check out our plug-in marketplace',
taglinecolor:'ffffff',
isActive:true
}"
```

How can i do this? Please Advice me.

Comment: why do you need to remove double quote ?

Comment: You wouldn't have JSON at that point anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string().It will remove the quotes.